# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to use Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to develop a mobile-based web application.
I am going to use HTML5 technologies.

I am currently using Eclipse Juno with IBM worklight.
I want to use MySQL RDMS. To access the data from that I would like to use Node.js.

Does anyone know of examples of how to use Node.js in Worklight?

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Worklight does not officially support Node.js*

See this blog post about Node.js and Worklight: [A preview of Node.js adapters in Worklight 6.0.0](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/a_preview_of_node_js_adapters_in_worklight_6_0_0?lang=en)